# How to make a simple division diagram to a base b?

Tags: math-mode

How can I typeset a simple diagram (dividend-quotient-remainder) in a base different to decimal? For example: `$120101_{3} \div 102_{3}$`

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Sigur I'm not 100% convinced that it is a duplicate. This one asks for doing it in a different base.

Comment: What do you mean with diagram, are you meaning to use a draw package such as `Tikz` or `pstricks` for draw it?

Comment: Aradnix, What I understand how diagram is similar to maker long division by Euclides Algorithm

Comment: This is not duplicated, since what is asking here is for a base b, which is not necessarily the base 10. This is not yet answered.